# Is it possible to disable target devices for the app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

In my app I want to enable only iPhone 4 and newer version, and iPod 4g.
is it possible and how to do this?
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you should target a version of iOS and not of the devices themselves. You can do that by changing the **iOS Deployment target**.

Some old devices don't support the newer versions of iOS, so if, for example, your target deployment is iOS 4.3, your app will not run on iPhone 3G devices.

If your app requires a specific device capability that is not available in older iOS devices, you can specify that in the info.plist file and the app will not be available for older devices. Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10) at the list of keys for the **Required Device Capabilities** field. (iPhone 3GS doesn't have a font facing camera for example).

But it is not recommended to not support iPhone 3GS if it has all the hardware requirements for your app. You loose some market share, and I am not sure Apple will validate your app.

Comment: To disable the app from loading on an iPad, you may also have to add telephony to the required capabilities.